# How to use a deferred to return the authentication secret when using Autobahn Wamp Cra?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I'm subclassing `WampCraServerProtocol` (from Autobahn Python) and overriding `getAuthSecret`. I understand that now I can return a deferred from that method, however, when doing a simple test:

```
def getAuthSecret(self, authKey):        
    deferred = Deferred()
    deferred.callback("secret")
    return deferred
```

... I get the following error on my `WampCraClientProtocol`:

`Authentication Error! http://api.wamp.ws/error#generic Deferred instance has no attribute '__len__' None`

Ok, that alone is confusing already. Are there special requirements over the deferred that `getAuthSecret` returns?

Ok, moving on, based on that error, I added a (trivial) **len** method to the deferred I'm returning:

```
def getAuthSecret(self, authKey):
    #secret_deferred = self.factory.get_secret(authKey)
    deferred = Deferred()
    deferred.__len__ = lambda: 1
    deferred.callback("secret")
    return deferred
```

... in that case, I get:

```
Authentication Error! http://api.wamp.ws/error#generic unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str' None
```

That confuses me even more.
I just want to know the correct way to return a deferred from that method.
(I should note that everything works perfectly if a return a plain simple string).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/wamp/authentication/server.py#L72

What AutobahnPython version are you using?

Update:

v0.5.9 has a bug regarding deferred based authentication (see comments below). It was fixed on v0.5.14. Wamp Cra deferred based authentication works fine on that version.

Comment: That should work for me, too. It's quite similar to my code. As per pip freeze, I'm using version 0.5.9.

Comment: I guess the issue you see was fixed after 0.5.9 (in commit https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/commit/3b2cd64d2489c4924095c6e406b2676a85967be8). I'd recommend to use the master or maintenance_v0_5 branch on GitHub, since there wasn't a release after 0.5.9 yet that was published on PyPi.

Comment: Solved! Indeed, v0.5.9 is broken in that regard. Everything worked fine after I checked out the Master branch. Thanks! I spent almost 4 hours hitting my head against the screen on friday. I suggest publishing the latest release to PyPi asap, though.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience;( We've now published 0.5.14 to PyPi.

Comment: No problem :) Excellent piece of software, Autobahn, by the way.